# Try to deploy app via PAServer 21 but in vain

Tags: rad-studio, paserver

This bothered me for over half a year already.
When I used Rad Studio 10.4.1, it is ok to deploy app to the iOS device.
While I installed Rad Studio 10.4.2 on another PC, and installed PAserver 21 (12.2.10.3) on another macbook, it failed to deploy app to the iOS device.

Connection seems to be ok...
[image]

Provisioning seems to be good...
[image]

But the compiler will stop at...
[image]

PAServer shows message like this
[image]

The process will hang there until I quit in PAServer
[image]

I have consulted with Embarcaderom but with no answer.
Can someone help to solve this problem?

Thanks with all my heart...

Comment: BTW...when I detach the iOS device...the compiler will show no error message. Only I stop the PAServer, the deploy will stop and show error message like the final image.

Comment: Still can't solve the problem...I wonder...is there no one have the same situation? I tried to change a Macbook Pro and a Macbook air with M1, and upgrade to Rad Studio 11 Alexandra, But all in vain. no matter I created the provision profile manually (Generate Certificate using Key chain -> Generate App ID-> Add Devices -> Generate Provision Profile) or created by Xcode automatically...They all stop when deployment...Only when I use community version of Rad Studio, it can successfully deploy a dummy app to the iOS device. But the dummy app does not work correctlly (will crash immediately).